# python package error in installation time

Tags: python, python-3.x, ubuntu, pip, installation

I am installing python and some other python packages. I am getting same error.
suggest me some. how can I fix.

```
palwesh@wg-palwesh:~$ sudo apt-get install python-pip
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 python-pip : Depends: python-pip-whl (= 9.0.1-2) but 9.0.1-2.3~ubuntu1.18.04.1 is to be installed
              Recommends: python-all-dev (>= 2.6) but it is not going to be installed
              Recommends: python-setuptools but it is not going to be installed
              Recommends: python-wheel but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
palwesh@wg-palwesh:~$
```

Answer (score 0):

First try `sudo apt-get update` to make sure your package lists are up to date.

"Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages." implies that you have used Apt's hold functionality to stop packages from being updated. (`apt-mark showhold` shows you the held packages, `apt-mark unhold` lets you remove relevant holds.)